# Docker creating dummy ethernet interface

Tags: docker, ethernet

Is it possible to create dummy Ethernet interface using Docker build below is snippet from DockerFile build logs.

```
   Step 14/17 : run sudo ip link add dummy0 type dummy && sudo ip addr add 192.168.10.12/24 dev dummy0 && sudo ip link set dummy0 up
     ---> Running in 21c388505e28
    RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
```

I was able to create dummy interface by running the image in privilege mode. Below commands were used to create dummy interface.

```
$ ip link add eth_dummy type dummy
$ ip addr add 172.16.1.1/24 dev eth_dummy
$ ip link set eth_dummy up
```

These commands requires privilege mode which docker build does not allows and how can I execute these commands everytime when containers is started from image.

Comment: Would be interesting if you could elaborate why you would want this.  Sure seems like effect could be handled differently using the docker network options or something.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the docker container with the option: `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN`. ([reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities))

Comment: This is not an option for `docker build`.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker build` command does not have the option to run privileged commands or to change capabilities on the embedded containers used during the build. The image build process is designed to be portable, run on different hosts, potentially in the cloud where servers do not trust the image being built.

Performing this during the image build also doesn't make sense. The output of a build command is the filesystem changes, stored as layers of an overlay (typically) filesystem. The changes to the network would be lost when you try to run the same image on another node. If those changes are isolated to the container network, then they would be lost at the end of the RUN step, before the next step of the Dockerfile is performed.

Instead, consider moving the logic into an entrypoint that runs when the container is started.